# Socket Beginconnect several times for the same socket while not connected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, client

I'm trying to connect a client to a server with an asynchronous socket in c#.

I'm doing socket.beginconnect to try to connect, the point is that if the connection is not established, I would like it to try to beginconnect, and if the connection is not established in 500ms, I would like to try it again for lets say, 10 times.

I tried a simple bucle but it doesn't work because I cant beginconnect again until the previous one is finished, but when the beginconnect finishes and don't find the server, it returns an expecion that there is no server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145129(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation says that:

> To cancel a pending call to the BeginConnect method, close the Socket.
>   When the Close method is called while an asynchronous operation is in
>   progress, the callback provided to the BeginConnect method is called.
>   A subsequent call to the EndConnect method will throw an
>   ObjectDisposedException to indicate that the operation has been
>   cancelled.

So you have to create a new Socket each time:

```
public Socket TryConnect(...)
{
    Socket socket;

    try
    {
        socket = new Socket(...);
        var connect = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            socket.BeginConnect, socket.EndConnect, host, port, null);

        var isConnected = connect.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));

        if (!isConnected)
        {
            socket.Close();
            return null;
        }

        return socket;      
    }
    catch
    {
        if (socket != null)
        {
            socket.Dispose();
        }
        throw;
    }
}


for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var socket = TryConnect();
    if (socket != null)
        return socket;
}
```