# C# BeginConnect cannot be called while another asynchronous operation is in progress on the same socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm playing around with some sockets, and the server part works fine with some previous vb.net code i wrote years ago, but i'm getting this error (see picture) https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEo1n.jpg
What is causing this?

```
        void Connect()
    {
        //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
        while (!Client.Connected)
        {                
            try
            {
                Client.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 64555), new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), Client);

            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    private void OnConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        socket.EndAccept(ar);
        Title = "Connected";
        Client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), socket);
    }
```

Comment: So how many thousand times are you going to call BeginConnect in that loop before OnConnect is called?

Comment: Oups, i see it clearly now. Thx

Answer (score 0):

As committed You create a new Socket every time the loop fired...

Try to open the socket only if fails...

And if you really want to open it again you have to create a new Socket each time...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41795143/4836581